# I'm trying to learn javascript

Tags: javascript

Create an object literal and assign it to a variable named car. It should 
contain a property named speed with a value of 30, as well as a method named 
increaseSpeed() with one parameter, milesPerHour, that should be used to  increase the object's speed.
This is the code I have.

```
var car = {
speed:30,

increaseSpeed(milesPerHour)
{
return this.speed + milesPerHour;
}

};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: [Assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a function to the key like:

```
var car = {
  speed:30,

  increaseSpeed: function(milesPerHour) {
    return this.speed + milesPerHour;
  }
};
```

Then you can call it like:

```
car.increaseSpeed(100);
```